# The video_player plugin only on Android plays .MOV files without rotation

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-video-player

Using the `video_player` plugin, when playing a video that was uploaded from iOS (recorded in iOS horizontally and volume buttons up), only on Android devices it is inverted, but in iOS it plays correctly, it also plays correctly when opened in a browser or any player.